# button looses focus when keypad comes up

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, listview, android-listview

I have edit text and a button next to it at the bottom of the screen and at the top of the screen is list view ,When I click on the edit text and the keyboard comes up under the button and edit text ,these both come over the list view and button is also not click able as far as the keyboard is open.
Please help.!
This is my Xml.

```
    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent" >

      <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="86dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="Send" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button1"
        android:ems="10" />

  </RelativeLayout>

  <ListView
      android:id="@android:id/list"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="317dp" 
    >

  </ListView>

        </FrameLayout>
```

Comment: post your xml so we can see

Comment: That's how it is supposed to work.

Comment: @tyczj check my xml in question

Comment: You shouldn't use absolute values for layout width and height. The answer by @MikeM looks good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is really odd behavior. With your layout, I got the same results. I'm not exactly sure why that button becomes unclickable.

However, if you don't absolutely have to have the FrameLayout that your layout is obviously contained in, then I suggest using the following:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Send" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```